# Not seeing any notifications in notifications bar except srange icon

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, notifications, samsung-galaxy-s-3

Recently I started seeing this strange icon in my notifications bar (see screenshot). At the same time, I stopped seeing any notification icons in the bar on top. I still get audibly notified, and they're there if I pull the notifications window down. But the notification bar remains as in the screenshot.

Any ideas what this might be?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The little arrow with the `-` means that you have status bar notifications disabled, which is why you're no longer seeing them. If you pull down the notification shade and then swipe the buttons to the right (I believe it's to the right anyway, check both directions) there should be a toggle to re-enable them:

[image]